# In Javascript two same looking strings are not equal?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server, string, bcrypt

I'm trying to compare two passwords , one from DB and other is user entered. The one from db is hashed and stored in binary format. So I have to conver it to string before comparing.

```
 console.log(
      user.PasswordHash.toString('base64') ===
        '$2a$10$UZptbo5h4lQFYmK352CPf.jDvPZh1pm3uC3Nb0wEVjF/RUCw2OU2G'
    ); //false
```

When I look in console user.PasswordHash.toString('base64') evaluates to `$2a$10$UZptbo5h4lQFYmK352CPf.jDvPZh1pm3uC3Nb0wEVjF/RUCw2OU2G` which is the same value.

What is happening?

```
bcrypt.compareSync(
      password,
      user.PasswordHash.toString('base64')); //false
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try it with double equal sign (==) rather than triple(===)?

Comment: Yes both returned false

Comment: Try assigning the toString output to a variable and compare with that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code you are sharing.. Is somewhere else.. My thesis is that you have an asynchronous problem meaning that the data is delivered after the code is executed. In that case the variable is undefined and the conditional statement will return false as in the following example:

```js
let x;

function isOne(input){
  return input === 1;
}

console.log(isOne(x))
```

Try implementing a promise https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_promise.asp

To see if it's an asynchronous problem you can use `setTimeout()`

Make sure you have the data and then execute your condition statement. Go step by step checking with `console.log()`

Comment: I'm sure it is not an async problem. I have an await up top. I even consoled logged and can see both the string before they are compared.

Comment: How do you know the console logs both strings before executes the comparison?

Comment: Did you try a ridiculous test?? just to be 100% certain... Like setting the `setTimeout()` with a 10 second delay to the conditional statement  ..